# Strange behaviour with \AtEndDocument

Tags: latex-base

I'm creating a document class that has draft and final versions. The final version has a front page generated by `\maketitle`, but in draft mode `\maketitle` is `\let` to `\relax`.  I decided to insert a test to ensure that `\maketitle` is present in final mode. The simplest method seemed to be to use `\AtEndDocument`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myexam}[2013/03/08 \space (v1.0) \space\space Ian Thompson]

\newif\iffinal %Option for final or draft mode                                                                                                          
\finalfalse %Default to draft mode                                                                                                                      
\DeclareOption{final}{\finaltrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\finalfalse}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\iffinal
  \typeout{FINAL MODE}
  \newif\ifmaketitle
  \maketitlefalse
  \AtEndDocument{\ifmaketitle\relax\else \ClassError{myexam}{Final version requires maketitle}{}\fi}
  \renewcommand\maketitle{THIS IS THE TITLE\newpage\maketitletrue}
\else
  \typeout{DRAFT MODE}
  \let\maketitle\relax
\fi
```

However, attempting to typeset this simple example file

```
\documentclass[draft]{myexam}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

results in the error

> ! Class myexam Error: Final version requires
>   maketitle

despite the fact that the example uses draft mode. Everything worked until I inserted `\AtEndDocument`. What is going on here?

Comment: changed tag [tex-core] to [latex-kernel].  still not sure if this is best choice, but [tex-core] would have been appropriate only if `\bye` were the trigger for the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need:

```
  \newif\ifmaketitle

 \iffinal
```

You need to always declare the new if otherwise the scanning of your `\iffinal` block goes wrong as `\ifmaketitle` is not an if but the `else` and `\fi` are (so terminate the `\iffinal`.